# Validate Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Can I use a [Validate mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Validate+Mediator#json) to validate diferent resources (diferent json-schemas) in the same API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this. You need to engage a custom sequence as explained in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Mediation+Extensions. It is always better to minimize the meditation done within the API Manager. If you need to do lots of mediation, better to move the mediation part to another mediation engine such as WSO2 ESB.

Comment: I don't understand your recommendation, because I always believed that APIM has a full ESB engine embebed. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I managed to build the following Mediator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="validateSomething" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('API_ELECTED_RESOURCE')" name="API_ELECTED_RESOURCE"/>
        <property expression="get-property('api.ut.HTTP_METHOD')" name="api.ut.HTTP_METHOD"/>
    </log>
    <switch source="get-property('API_ELECTED_RESOURCE')">
        <case regex="/v1/myResource/\{id\}">
            <filter regex="GET" source="get-property('api.ut.HTTP_METHOD')">
                <then>
                    <validate>
                        <schema key="conf:/schema/ObjectSchema.json"/>
                        <on-fail>
                            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                                <format>{"Error validating JSON returned by the Backend":$1}</format>
                                <args>
                                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
                                </args>
                            </payloadFactory>
                            <property name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="500"/>
                            <respond/>
                        </on-fail>
                    </validate>
                </then>
                <else/>
            </filter>
        </case>
        <default>
            <respond/>
        </default>
    </switch>
</sequence>
```